# jQuery multiple value filter on table

Tags: jquery, input, filter

I'm trying to filter a table with multiple keywords, if a `tr` contain all the keywords, then it display. I found something that work great on a  `ul`, but behave strangly on a table. Here the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AtkNW/81/

The filter seems to only check the second or third `td` of each `tr`. What i'm missing ? I could use a hand.

```
$("#kwd_search").keyup(function () {

var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase(),
    count = 0;
var length = $(this).val().length;
if (length > 1) {
    var filter_tags = filter.split(" ");
    $("#dep td").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var matches = true;
        $.each(filter_tags, function (i, a_filter) {
            if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(a_filter) === -1) {
                matches = false;
            }
        });
        if (matches) {
            $this.parent("tr").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $this.parent("tr").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
} else {
    $("#dep td").parent("tr").removeClass("hidden");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/E9bTu/1

your code bug was that after traversing all `td` you change match value false.

i.e. if last value matches than only your code runs fine.

i changed the code i run code for each `tr` n than for `td` contained in it and also replaced the code by default `matches=0` when match is found `matches=1`.

After traversing all `td` in one `tr` if `matches=1` than i remove class `hidden`

added `filter_tags_length` to calculate length of filter tags.

After traversing all `td` in one `tr` sets `matches=1` if `filter_tags_length` is equal to variable `c`.

```
$("#kwd_search").keyup(function () {

    var filter = $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase());
    count = 0;
    var length = $.trim($(this).val().length);
    if (length > 1) {
        var filter_tags = filter.split(" ");
        var filter_tags_length = filter_tags.length;
        $("#dep tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
            count++;
            i = 0;
            matches = 0;
            c = 0;
            $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var lenght_td = $this.parents('tr').find('td').length;
                i++;
                $.each(filter_tags, function (i, a_filter) {
                    if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(a_filter) !== -1) {
                        c++;
                        if (c == filter_tags_length) {
                            matches = 1;
                        }
                    }
                });
                // console.log(matches);
                if (i == lenght_td) {
                    if (matches > 0) {
                        $(this).parents("tr").removeClass("hidden");
                    } else {
                        $(this).parents("tr").addClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            });
            //console.log('next'+count);
        });
    } else {
        $("#dep td").parent("tr").removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Tushar. I was thinking about some problem with the index, but it's far more complex than i thought, thank for your help. Just one thing, i want to display only the `tr` that match all the keywords, and not the `tr` that match one of the keywords. I can't figure why the improvement you've make change the behavior.

Comment: you mean if you enter two keywords together  ?

Comment: Yeah, if i type "hi bye", i want to display only the `tr` that contain "hi" and "bye".

Comment: added little more explanation ..!!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this today for a similar purpose... hope it helps!

```
$("#kwd_search").keyup(function () {
    var jqSearchBox = $(this);
    var rows = $("#dep > tbody > tr");

    if (jqSearchBox.val().length < 2) {
        rows.show();
        return;
    } else {
        rows.hide();
    }

    // split, trim, lowercase, and remove empty strings
    var searchTerms = $.map(jqSearchBox.val().toLowerCase().split(" "), function (el) {
        return el !== "" ? $.trim(el) : null;
    });

    rows.each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var foundAll = true;

        $.each(searchTerms, function (idx, val) {
            if (row.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) === -1) {
                foundAll = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (foundAll)
            row.show();                 
    });
});
```